# Can't reach link th:src route on thymeleaf

Tags: java, css, spring, hyperlink, thymeleaf

Well, that's nothing more, tried everything, googled and still unsolving this tricky problem,

I'll be glad if you can help me with this!

Here you can see how it looks;
[image]

Here is the css code;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="/static/assets/css/style.css"
th:href="@{/assets/css/style.css}" media="screen" type="text/css"></link>
```

And here you can see the organization of my files.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem?It does not find the css file?Do you have a style.css file inside your css folder?Where do you put this code in your html page?

Comment: The problem css is not working neither images attached on the html

Comment: http://prntscr.com/glgv5e here you can see the html code, i really dont see which is the problem, and of course i have css code inside my css folder you can check it here http://prntscr.com/glgvjg

Comment: still happening the same i'll be glad if you can help me, i'm not experienced with routes:  code here: http://prntscr.com/gljtee

and here you can see the organization of my files: http://prntscr.com/gljto5

Comment: and yeah, it does not find the css file, and yes i have

Answer (score 0):

In your html code start with this

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

In addition , delete the src from the link and replace it with href

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/assets/css/style.css"
th:href="@{/assets/css/style.css}" media="screen" type="text/css"></link>
```

Comment: the css works, but even the route from standart html is not working!

Comment: /C:/assets/css/style.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: if i take and find the css using the chrome explorer manually it shows this route : file:///C:/PROGRAMACION/workspacemichaeleclipse/inventario/src/main/resources/static/assets/css/style.css

Comment: if i copy paste the route i'm using (href="/assets/css/style.css" )it shows in the chrome console is :   
/C:/assets/css/style.css

Comment: looks like even isn't thymeleaf , but basic html routing!

Comment: can someone help me here?

Comment: finally managed to make it work on html, but on thymeleaf still not running..


<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css"
 th:href="@{../static/css/style.css}" type="text/css"></link>

Answer (score 0):

Do this. Pay attention to the '..' and rel="stylesheet"

`<link href="../static/assets/css/style.css" th:href="@{/assets/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet">`